# Weird control characters in ruby test output inside emacs buffer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, emacs

I'm using ruby-test to run rails tests from inside emacs into the *Ruby-Test* buffer. It works great except that the output is cluttered with ascii color-control characters (not sure what the right terminology is).

Example:

```
MyTest:
    ^[[32m     PASS^[[0m Test Passed (2.85s)
```

If I run the test in a terminal that shows up as a green "PASS". Is there something I can do to get the colors to show up in my output buffer?

There's a related question about getting color for commands run with M-|, but I couldn't figure out how to adapt it for a generic buffer.

[emacs shell command output not showing ANSI colors but the code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5819719/emacs-shell-command-output-not-showing-ansi-colors-but-the-code)

Answer (score 1):

In order to get Emacs to guess ansi-color mode for regular buffers, use:

```
(require 'tty-format)
(add-hook 'find-file-hooks 'tty-format-guess)
```

You need to [download](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TtyFormat) the tty-format package first.
See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19494/how-to-colorize-text-in-emacs

Looking at the code, it looks like the author's made a bunch of questionable decisions, but maybe this will help:

```
(defadvice ruby-test-runner-sentinel (after add-ansi-colors activate compile)
  (ansi-color-apply-on-region (point-min) (point-max)))
```

Comment: This is promising, but it didn't work completely. I now get colors if I save the output of the *Ruby-Test* buffer to a text file and then open that file, but just going to the buffer doesn't show the colors (even if I force text-mode). Also I can use the  ansi-color-apply-on-region-int function defined in your link manually on the region, but how do I make it automatic?

Comment: I added a defadvice which may help.  A word of warning:  a lot of the stuff I see in this package make me want to look for alternatives if I were about to use it.

Comment: No luck with that, maybe because the invoke-test-file function completes before the output of the test is piped back to the buffer?

Comment: you're right.  advice the sentinel instead then.  see my modified answer.

Comment: Unfortunately I'd preemptively tried that to no avail. Could you explain what add-ansi-colors is doing? I can't find it in any help. I also tried removing the filename regex tests in tty-format-guess.

Comment: ok isee tty-format-guess is the wrong thing to call.  Maybe call my ansi-color-apply-on-region then.  see my modification.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3903/discussion-between-event-jr-and-spike)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have [ansi-color.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ansi-color.el) installed and active? [See this also.](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AnsiColor)

Comment: I have run (requre 'ansi-color) and am using emacs 23.2, so I think so.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the

```
ansi-color-for-coming-mode-on
```

function in this buffer

Comment: I tried this (ansi-color-for-comint-mode-on) but it didn't work.  The docs state that it only affects "shell buffers". Do you know what that means?